# Create stack where the elements are arrays

Tags: c++, qt, stack

In my Qt project i have enum:

```
enum Field {EMPTY=0, WHITE=1, BLACK=2};
```

And array of this enum:

```
Field field[8][8];
```

Now i need create Stack of this array. Ever element of stack must be field[8][8]. How can i make it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct FieldMatrix { Field fields[8][8]; };

// not familiar with Stack, but here's the standard library stack type
std::stack<FieldMatrix> foo;
```